# Crash on substring

Tags: java, substring

I don't know why, but if I make a substring the app crashes!

Here's the code:

```
while(data_mio.moveToNext())
{
    titolo_da_inserire=data_mio.getString(prodotto);
    titolo_da_inserire=titolo_da_inserire.substring(0,35)+"...";
    personList.add( new Prodotto_per_lista(
                      R.drawable.freccia_1, titolo_da_inserire,
                      Integer.parseInt(data_mio.getString(id_immagine)))
                  );
}
```

Comment: are you sure your String titolo_da_inserire has a min length of 35 chars?

Comment: don't know... it's maybe the problem? in php it's not a problem, but here it could be.. let me check

Comment: post the stacktrace after the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually declare `String  titolo_da_inserire` like,

```
String titolo_da_inserire = "";
```

Now, before using `subString()` **check the length** of String titolo_da_inserire

```
if(titolo_da_inserire.length() >= 35)
 titolo_da_inserire = titolo_da_inserire.substring(0,35)+"...";
else
 titolo_da_inserire = titolo_da_inserire.substring(0,titolo_da_inserire.length())+"...";
```

Comment: @BorisStrandjev - Only checking `Null` left..  empty string will be `length of 0`.

Comment: Ah sorry I misread your code. But, actually, for me it makes sense to be:
`if(titolo_da_inserire.length() >= 35)
titolo_da_inserire=titolo_da_inserire.substring(0,35)+"...";
else
titolo_da_inserire=titolo_da_inserire.substring(0,titolo_da_inserire.length())+"...";
`

Comment: Perfect. Now my comment about the zero length makes sense.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev - Yeah... Now it make a sense... But there is no need to check for it.. As It never throws exceptions... :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your `titolo_da_inserire` **String** has less then 35 then it will throw `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` that's way your app is crashed

**Sample**

```
String st ="string";

st = st.substring(0,15); // throws exception String index out of range

System.out.println(st);
```

so you need to do a check of length

```
if(st.length()>15)

{

st = st.substring(0,15);

System.out.println(st);

}
```